# Upload Parse Object with RxJava

Tags: android, parse-platform, rx-java

I would like to wrap a synchronous method from parse.com mainly ParseObject.save() into a RxJava wrapper. I have come up with the below:

```
public Observable<Void> uploadFix(final ParseObject parseObject) {
    return Observable.defer(new Func0<Observable<Void>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<Void> call() {
            try {
                return Observable.just(fix.save());
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                return Observable.error(e);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

This is giving me an error: Observable cannot be applied to void.

Basically is there any way to wrap this call with RxJava and get notified if the save is successful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fix.save()` returns void so you can't use it as an argument to `Observable.just()`. You can return a boolean instead.

```
public Observable<Boolean> uploadFix(final ParseObject parseObject) {
    return Observable.defer(new Func0<Observable<Boolean>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<Boolean> call() {
            try {
                fix.save();
                return Observable.just(true);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                return Observable.error(e);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, one question though, if you have a Observable <Boolean> from that and want to compare it to primitive boolean how would you proceed? With Map?

Comment: @ReneGens depends on where do you get the boolean from, what do you need to do with the result. If `map()` works for you then why not.

Answer (score 0):

you could also use a Completable. It is used when you don't except a return-value. If RxJava for Android will bump-up to version 2, you can not use Observabl anymore, because null values are not allowed anymore.

Please look at my example. I am using RxJava2-RC5 for testing. Test should complete within 2 seconds + overhead.

```
@org.junit.Test
public void name() throws Exception {
        Completable completable = Completable.fromAction(() -> doWorkSync());

        TestObserver<Void> test = completable.test();

        test.assertComplete();
}

private void doWorkSync() {
        // simulate work
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2_000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, but I haven't switched yet to rxjava 2.